# EEPROM 25LC1024 issue with PIC32MX OLIMEX board

Tags: pic, spi, eeprom, timing-analysis

I am trying to read the status register for the EEPROM following the instructions in this Application Note. I wanted to have the opinion of the community on the signals I am getting. They don't seem normal to me.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01073A.pdf

Wiring Diagram: I am using the exact same pinout recommended in the Application Note.

When I read MISO, I get a strange behavior.
[image: Output of the EEPROM]

MOSI and CS Signals:

I get the MOSI signal as expected on rising edge.
[image: Input to the EEPROM]

[image: Chip Select sync with Clock]

I setup the clock to tick @1MHz

SPI Initialization code, and running code in my main.c. (from eewiki, adapted to my needs)

```
#define eepromCS LATBbits.LATB15
void initSPI(void)
{
// Add GPIO config on pin RB15
eepromCS = 1; //GND


IEC0bits.SPI1EIE = 0;
IEC0bits.SPI1RXIE = 0;
IEC0bits.SPI1TXIE = 0;


SPI2CONbits.ON = 0;

SPI2BUF = 0;

SPI2BRG = 0; // 1MHZ

SPI2STATbits.SPIROV = 0;

/* SPI2CON Settings */
SPI2CONbits.FRMEN = 0;
SPI2CONbits.SIDL = 0;
SPI2CONbits.DISSDO = 0;

// 8 bits !
SPI2CONbits.MODE16 = 0;
SPI2CONbits.MODE32 = 0;

SPI2CONbits.CKP = 0; // Active state is high
SPI2CONbits.CKE = 0; // sampling from idle to active
SPI2CONbits.SSEN = 0;
SPI2CONbits.MSTEN = 1;
SPI2CONbits.SMP = 0; // sample during transmission

SPI2CONbits.ON = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
TRISBbits.TRISB15 = 0;
CSEEPROM = 1; 


initSPI(); //EEPROM as a slave
unsigned char status;
unsigned char tmp;

//First READ
while (!SPI2STATbits.SPITBE);
eepromCS = 0;
SPI2BUF = 0x05;
while (!SPI2STATbits.SPIRBF);
status = SPI2BUF;
SPI2BUF = 0;
while (!SPI2STATbits.SPIRBF);
status = SPI2BUF;
eepromCS = 1;
write_char(status);


//Enable write LATCH
while (!SPI2STATbits.SPITBE);
eepromCS = 0;
SPI2BUF = 0x06;
while (!SPI2STATbits.SPIRBF);
tmp = SPI2BUF;
eepromCS = 1;


//Read Status register
while (!SPI2STATbits.SPITBE);
eepromCS = 0;
SPI2BUF = 0x05;
while (!SPI2STATbits.SPIRBF);
status = SPI2BUF;
SPI2BUF = 0;
while (!SPI2STATbits.SPIRBF);
status = SPI2BUF;
eepromCS = 1;
//write_char(status);

while (42);
return 0;
}
```

I did screenshots only for the last two operations (write latch enable, and read from status register). I have exactly the same signals when I read the status register before I send the write latch command.

I am using PIC32MX Olimex prototyping board, Below the protoboard documentation and EEPROM datasheet.

https://www.olimex.com/Products/PIC/Proto/PIC-32MX/resources/PIC-32MX.pdf
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22064B.pdf

As usual the devil is in the details, it would be great if I could have a new look on my issue. Maybe I missed something.

Thank you for your help !

PS: increasing the baud to match 20MHz makes the signal flat but doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like anything code-related. It looks like either a pin shorted to another output pin which is set to zero ( or another slave not tri-stating its MISO ). Disconnect the memory chip, set PIC MISO to output and try to toggle it by writing 1 and 0 to the corresponding port bit.

Another suspect is power supply to the memory chip. Make sure it receives VCC and has a capacitor from VCC to ground.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try your solutions, and it doesn't work. I did some tests with the multimeter and I discovered something horrifying. Current doesn't flow into the EEPROM. I actually have 2, I hope I didn't short circuited them both. I have a generator with 5V and I am testing current with a multimeter. It stays @ 0 microA Any clue as to how I could debug it ? I tried other circuits too, and I am getting the same result

Comment: If the chip is not damaged, you won't be able to see current into this chip with a multimeter. Did you try to toggle MISO as suggested?

Comment: I tried to enable RG7 as suggested and I get the right ouput line. I even tried to change the prototyping board, and nothing happens. It must be something small. I have to start everything from the beginning

Comment: I would like to point out that I was trying to get the operating current in the multimeter, I don't understand why I would not be able to see current ? In the datasheet it says that in Standby mode, I would get between 12 and 20 microA imgur.com/a/bu4lNd8 –